# They could help me with JTable displays data and how?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I'm creating a generic draft model table used to any table in a database. The idea is that the JTable model instantiating take this class, passing only the table of the database to query.

It is not yet finished, and see that there's parameters, but not used.

The problem is that I extend to AbstractTableModel and gender data with an array of Object [] [], which makes me lose data type.

To solve that I get the data classes of a ResultSetMetaData columns and stored in an array.

Overwrite the getColumnClass () method to return my class stored in said array, but when the table is assembled, the Integer still appear flush left, like String.

Les step hoping one can give an account of where the error, or omission is found code.

```
package com.reclamos.jpa.utilitarios;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class GeneracionTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5487182325989883781L;
public GeneracionTableModel(JTable tabla, String pTabla, String[] titulosColumnas){
    //this.tabla = tabla;
    this.pTabla = pTabla;
    this.titulosColumnas = titulosColumnas;
    conexion = null;
    sqlString = null;
    sentencia = null;
    rs = null;
    obtenerDatos();
}

public void obtenerDatos(){
    try {
        conexion = new Conexion();
        sqlString = "SELECT * FROM " + pTabla;
        sentencia = conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(sqlString);
        rs = sentencia.executeQuery();
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        crearTableModel(rs);
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha producido el siguiente error: " + sqle.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try {
            rs.close(); //ver de mover al mï¿½todo en donde se llena el TableModel, para que se cierre antes de leerlo
            conexion.getConexion().close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ha producido el siguiente error: " + sqle.getMessage());
        }
    }

}


public void crearTableModel(ResultSet resultSet){
    try {
        resultSet.last();
        ultimaFila = resultSet.getRow();
        resultSet.first();

        clases = new Class[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
        for(int puntero=0; puntero < rsmd.getColumnCount();puntero++ ){
            Class<?> clase = Class.forName(rsmd.getColumnClassName(puntero+1));
            //System.out.println(clase);
            clases[puntero] = clase;
            //System.out.println(clases[puntero].getClass().toString());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CrearTableModel-Clases: " + clases[puntero]);
        }

        /**
        HashMap hashColumnas = new HashMap<Integer, Class<?>>();
        for(int puntero=0; puntero < rsmd.getColumnCount(); puntero++){
            String clase = rsmd.getColumnClassName(puntero+1) + ".class";
            hashColumnas.put(puntero, Class.forName(clase));
            System.out.println(hashColumnas.get(puntero));
        }
        */

        fila = new Object[ultimaFila][rsmd.getColumnCount()];
        for (int punteroFilas = 1; punteroFilas <= ultimaFila; punteroFilas++) {
            for (int punteroColumnas = 0; punteroColumnas < titulosColumnas.length; punteroColumnas++) {
                //String tipoDato = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(punteroColumnas+1);
                //System.out.println(tipoDato);
                fila[punteroFilas-1][punteroColumnas] = resultSet.getString(punteroColumnas+1);
                //System.out.println(fila[punteroColumnas]);
            }
            rs.next();
        }

        //tabla.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CrearTableModel-CNFE-Se ha producido el siguiente error: " + cnfe.getMessage());
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CrearTableModel-SQL-Se ha producido el siguiente error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try {
            rs.close();
            conexion.getConexion().close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CrearTableModel-Finally-Se ha producido el siguiente error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    //System.out.println(clases[columnIndex].getClass());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "GetColumnClass: " + clases[columnIndex].toString());
    return clases[columnIndex].getClass();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount(){
    try {
        return rsmd.getColumnCount();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return ultimaFila;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    return fila[row][col];
}

/**
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] titulos = {"IdLocalidad", "Descripciï¿½n"};
    new GeneracionTableModel("localidades", titulos );
}
*/

private Conexion conexion;
private String pTabla;
private Object[][] fila;
private String[] titulosColumnas;
private String sqlString;
private PreparedStatement sentencia;
private ResultSet rs;
private ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
private int ultimaFila;
private Class<?>[] clases;

private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
//private JTable tabla;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for a couple of solutions.

1. The `TableFromDatabaseExample` code shows a simple solution while using the DefaultTableModel.
2. The `ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet(...)` method uses a custom generic ListTableModel. It is more complex to understand but has many more features.